# Pros and cons of different file system options when creating an encrypted volume using VeraCrypt?

Tags: windows, mac, encryption, veracrypt

When creating a volume using VeraCrypt, it first asks whether you'll be adding files in excess of 4TB (I clicked yes), and then it prompts for a file system:

[image]

The options are:

- Mac OS Extended
- exFAT
- APFS

What are the tradeoffs between the different options? I believe exFAT can handle both macOS and Windows, but I'm not sure if it's slower? Also, Mac OS Extended is the default option, does that indicates it's better in some way? TL;DR, what are the key considerations when determining which file system option will to use?

Answer (score 2):

If you were to do the same task on Windows, it would offer you NTFS & ExFAT - two file systems capable of being read & written natively by Windows.

As you're apparently setting this up on Mac, you get the ones Mac can read & write natively.

ExFAT would be the compromise, but be aware that it cannot correctly hold file permissions, resource forks or extended attributes, so it is a compromise, not an ideal.
If you don't need cross-platform, HFS+ would be the 'safest' Mac option, as it can be used by any macOS right back to OS X 10.0. APFS only since High Sierra, 10.13.
[HFS+ is also the easiest to fix if it goes wrong. There are as yet no tools capable of dealing with APFS 'in depth'.]

The probable reason for the 4GB question is that otherwise it may also have offered you FAT32 as an option, which has a 4GB file size limit.